# How to get a hidden value from HTML?

Tags: jquery, html

```
<p id="sub-total">
<strong>Total</strong>: <span id="stotal"></span></p>
<p><input type="submit" id="submit-order" value="Submit" class="btn"/></p>
```

How to get "stotal" value from the HTML and pass to server. Now the value is coming from jQuery.

Comment: use jQuery itself or you can do it using JS as `document.getElementById('stotal').value`.

Comment: Why you have written hidden values in question?

Comment: `$("#stotal").text();` should give you the value

Comment: There could exist some other better ways to supply / pass that value to the server, if the question is asked right about JSF (with examples including related JSF components).

Comment: Very misleading question. You don't have any hidden values in your example...

Answer (score 4):

YOu can get using jquery by this.

```
var stotal=$("#stotal").text();
```

Comment: Since inside your span it is blank that's why it is not showing any thing. Give some text inside `<span>`. e.g. `<span id="stotal">xyz</span>`.

Answer (score 1):

hoep this will help you.

```js
$('#submit-order').click('click', function(event){
        
  // set the span value
  var span_val = $('#stotal').text();
  if(span_val=="")
    {
        alert("span value is null");
    }
  else
    {
        alert(span_val);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="sub-total">
<strong>Total</strong>: <span id="stotal"></span></p>
<p><input type="submit" id="submit-order" value="Submit" class="btn"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#stotal').html();  
// it will give you what ever text <span> tag contains.
```

Comment: This will give us html content does it??

Comment: Ya <span> tag do not have a value attribute in it.

Comment: Because there is nothing in span tag : <span id="stotal"></span>